# Read float values until ENTER

Tags: c++, cin, getline

I have to multiply two polynomials.

Input:
2 lines of text each containing 1 to 1000 coefficients (floats) separated by spaces.

Output:
Result of multiplication.

I already found the function that will multiply them, but I have no idea how to read the data.
Can you give me some ideas please? And an example would be nice.
Usually in that kind of "homeworks" I know the degree BEFORE entering coefficients...

Answer (score 0):

If the numbers are simply separated by spaces, you should be able to use `operator>>`, since it assumes whitespace-separated input:

```
std::vector<float> coeffs;
std::ifstream ifs("coeffs.txt");
float c;

while(ifs >> c) {
    coeffs.push_back(c);
}

ifs.close();
```

Comment: Well, that is a good idea, but after entering coeffs (separated by spaces) and hitting ENTER I'm still in this while loop. The only way to to get out of it is CTRL+C or CTRL+D.

Comment: @user2225809 Learn to use the standard library. I don't know what you are doing wrong, but <CTRL>+<D> "solving" the "problem" suggests me that you are trying to read from standard input. Of course you'll need to send an "end of file" if that is the case -- not if you are indeed reading from a *real* file.